# openCV Android camera orientation

Tags: android, opencv

Hello I am new in OpenCV and Android, I'm running the tutorial examples, nevertheless the camera orientation is rotated, I have tried this code to fix it:

```
 mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
 Mat mRgbaT = mRgba.t();
 Core.flip(mRgba.t(), mRgbaT, 1);
 Imgproc.resize(mRgbaT, mRgbaT, mRgba.size());
 return mRgbaT;
```

This works fine for a minute or so, frames are captured and represented correctly during one minute, but after that I get a SIGSev BpMemory fail and the application crashes.

Is there any workaround to change the camera orientation without having to do a flip and image resize?

May thanks for your help and advice.

Comment: did you ever figure out how to fix this? having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `android.hardware.Camera` and a custom camera application, your issue is probably that it defaults to layout mode, and that is probably what is setting the orientation when you transform it into a mat.

Can you provide some more context for how you are passing camera output into the module where you are using openCV?

After you open the camera call:

```
mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to change the orientation.

```
Mat draw = new Mat(mRgba.rows(),mRgba.cols(),mRgba.type());
Mat show = new Mat(mRgba.rows(),mRgba.cols(),mRgba.type());
Mat how = new Mat(mRgba.rows(),mRgba.cols(),mRgba.type());
Core.transpose(draw,how);
Imgproc.resize(how, show, show.size(),0,0,0);
Core.flip(show,draw,1);
return draw;
```